# Containment of ACC$^0$ in TC$^0$

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

The [Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:A#acc0) states that ACC$^0$ is contained in TC$^0$ and links to the paper [On ACC and Threshold Circuits](https://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/focs/1990/2082/00/089583.pdf).  However, what the linked paper proves is that depth-3 threshold circuits of quasipolynomial size can simulate ACC$^0$ circuits.

Wouldn't it be necessary to prove that constant depth threshold circuits of polynomial size simulate them rather than quasipolynomial?  Is it obvious how to do the simulation with just a polynomial number of gates?

Answer (score 1):

You can show directly how to simulate a polynomial fan-in modular gate using polynomially many threshold gates. The idea is that given inputs $x_1,\ldots,x_m$, you can use two threshold gates and an AND gate to determine whether $x_1 + \cdots + x_m = w$ for any $w$. Taking at most $m+1$ copies of this gadget and ORing them, we can simulate a single modular gate.

Comment: Is there a paper that fills in the details of how to perform the construction you described?

Comment: It's at the level of an exercise. Perhaps you can find it in textbooks.